# 3D Matrix multiplication in numpy and theano

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, theano.scan

I have a matrix A with size `(5,7,3)` and a matrix B with size `(5,3,8)`. I want to multiply them `C = A.B`, and the size of C is `(5,7,8)`.

It means that one 2D submatrix with size `(7,3)` in matrix A will be multiplied with one 2D submatrix with size `(3,8)` in matrix B respectively. So I have to multiply 5 times.

The simplest way is using a loop and numpy:

```
for u in range(5):
    C[u] = numpy.dot(A[u],B[u])
```

Is there any way to do this without using a loop? 
Is there any equivalent method in Theano to do this without using scan?

Answer (score 3):

Can be done pretty simply with `np.einsum` in numpy.

```
C = numpy.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', A, B)
```

It can also simply be:

```
C = numpy.matmul(A,B)
```

Since the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul) state:

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly

Theano has similar functionaly of [batched_dot](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#linear-algebra) so it would be

```
C = theano.tensor.batched_dot(A, B)
```

Comment: In Theano, I found that theano.tensor.batched_dot(X, Y) can do it.